# Iterate in Angular expression

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I got this HTML:

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="report in reportSummary">
    <td class="reports-list-table-column-device-category" 
        data-ng-if="report.deviceCategory.length !== 1">
        <button popover="{{report.deviceCategory[0].name}}" 
        popover-title="Multi-category" type="button" class="btn btn-default">
             Multi-category
          </button>
   </td>
</tr>
```

and I want to iterate through report.deviceCategory[] in popover. How can I make it in HTML?

Anybody giving minus, justify it.

Comment: one more ng-repeat? ng-repeat="items in report.deviceCategory"

Comment: I want to iterate in my popover. Can you point a bit more clearly your idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using a custom filter. `<button popover="report.deviceCategory | customFilter">`

Your filter would receive the the `deviceCategory` array, inside the filter just put your string together and return it.  This way you avoid the 2nd ng-repeat and the the button repeating.

[Angular Filters](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_09)

```
angular.module('filters.module',[])
  .filter('customeFltr',function(){
    return function(input){
      _len = input.length;
      _output = '';
      for(var i=0;i<_len;i++)
        _output += input[i].name + ', ';
      _output = _output.substring(0,(_output.length - 2));
      return _output
    }
  }); // end filter.module
```

EDIT 3/2021

```
angular.module('filters.module', [])
  .filter('customFltr', () => {
    return function(input){
      return input.reduce((acc, val) => {
        return `${acc}, ${val.name}`
      }, '')
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

just use `$index`

```
report.deviceCategory[$index].name
```

Update : you can do `ng-repeat` inside `ng-repeat`

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="report in reportSummary">
    <td class="reports-list-table-column-device-category" 
            data-ng-if="report.deviceCategory.length !== 1">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="device in report.deviceCategory">
                <button popover="{{device.name}}" 
            popover-title="Multi-category" type="button" class="btn btn-default">
                 Multi-category
              </button>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Nope, $index will give me only ng-repeat index, and what I need is yet another (from 0 to deviceCategory[n].length) index.

Comment: then you can do ng-repeat in ng-repeat.

Comment: That makes multiple buttons... and that is not what I need. I want iterated array deviceCategory in my popover="...".

Answer (score 0):

If your popover allows templates, try this (as mentioned by STEVER):

```html
<tr data-ng-repeat="report in reportSummary">
    <td class="reports-list-table-column-device-category" data-ng-if="report.deviceCategory.length !== 1">
        <button popover-template="template.html" popover-title="Multi-category" type="button" class="btn btn-default">
             Multi-category
        </button>
   </td>
</tr>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="template.html">
    <ul>
        <li data-ng-repeat="item in report.deviceCategory">{{item}}</li>
    </ul>
</script>
```